# If I set the build architecture as 32bit in Xcode, do my app runs on 64bit machines?

Tags: xcode, macos, architecture, 32bit-64bit

A basic question about building in 32/64 architecture with Xcode

If I set the build architecture as 32bit in Xcode, do my app runs on 64bit machines?
Is it going to run much slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 32 bit apps run just fine on 64 bit OS X. They may run slightly *faster* or *slower* in certain cases, but the difference is generally negligible. The only real limitation is the size of your virtual address space, i.e. 4 GB for a 32 bit app.

Comment: What are the consequences of having a virtual address space of different size?

Comment: Only the obvious one that if you need to allocate more than 4 GB of memory then you have a problem. Not many apps need to do this but if your app is working with very large data structures then it could potentially be an issue.

Comment: Another limitation is that automatic reference counting is not available in 32-bit apps.